# Close other menus on page before new one opens

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    var pull_1 = $('#pull-main-menu');
    var menu_1 = $('#mobile-menu');

    pull_1.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDeenter code herefault()
        `enter code here`;
        menu_1.slideToggle();
    });
});

$(function () {
    var pull_2 = $('#pull-first-menu');
    var menu_2 = $('#first-menu-top-left');

    pull_2.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu_2.slideToggle();
    });
});

$(function () {
    var pull_3 = $('#pull-second-menu');
    var menu_3 = $('#welcome');

    pull_3.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu_3.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="pull-main-menu"></a>
    <div id="mobile-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


 <a href="#" id="pull-first-menu"></a>
    <ul id="first-menu-top-left">
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <ul>
```

I have 3 functions which open 3 different menus on a page. I just can't figure out how to write conditions for these functions that will close the opened menu before new one gets opened.

Comment: Add relevant `HTML` also

Comment: can i see your `HTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter your html a little to use classes, and combine all those functions into one. Run the snippet below to see it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ddtoggle').click(function(e){
      $(this).next('.ddmenu').slideToggle();  
      $('.ddmenu').not($(this).next('.ddmenu')).hide()
    }).next('.ddmenu').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="ddtoggle" id="pull-main-menu">menu 1</a>
<div id="mobile-menu"  class="ddmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">menu item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">menu item 1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div> 

<a href="#" class="ddtoggle" id="pull-first-menu">menu 2</a>
<ul id="first-menu-top-left" class="ddmenu">
    <li><a href="">menu item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">menu item 2</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: It is working!) thanks for transforming my super functional 20-line code)))) I thought it's only possible with condition statement...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common class for your a elements (e.g pull-menu). In such a case you can have one function instead of 3:

```
$(function () {
    $(".pull-menu").bind("click", function(evt){
       $(".pull-menu").not($(this)).next("ul").hide();
       $(this).next("ul").slideToggle();//Or slideDown()
       evt.preventDefault();

    })
});
```